# Gradle: how to make copySpec from/include required?

Tags: gradle

Gradle: how to make copySpec from/include required?

```
processResources {

    from ("/path/foo") {
        include 'conf.xml'   <--- required
    }
}
```

If the dir "/path/foo" does not exist or the  file "conf.xml" does not found, no error.

How to make gradle build fail if the file not found? i.e., /path/foo/conf.xml is required for build.

I can check file existence like:

```
File file = new File("/path/foo/conf.xml")
if (!file.exists())
   ...
```

There are many places like these. Almost all files in copySpec are required, not optional.

Answer (score 0):

`CopySpec` provides no such functionality for it. Checking for the file as you have given is your option. You can configure a copy task to first check for the file prior to the tasks execution:

```
processResources {
    doFirst {
        File file = new File("/path/foo/conf.xml")
        if (!file.exists()) {
            // ...
        }
    }
    from("/path/foo") {
        include 'conf.xml'
    }
}
```